# Plans and pricing generic app?

Tags: django, quota

I'm in need of adding a plans and pricing schema to my website to charge a user for the use of certain feature. In this case, the `User` adds `Notices` to `Points`.

A `User` should not be able to add more `Notices` than his' `Plan` allows. Stuff like that.

A quick google round gave me nothing to look around (django pricing and plans are terrible search terms) so i was thinking in rolling my own solution but may be you know of something of interest.

I'm not very sold to the way the pricing schema would work or how to handle the pricing, but that's not in the scope of the question.

Comment: I don't think pricing is a good tag, but I cannot create one that fits better.

Comment: I'd go with `price-plans` or `pricing-plans`. +1, having the same problem.

Comment: if its a subscription based system use the built-in stripe stuff: https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=python

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We are actively developing a possible solution:

https://github.com/cypreess/django-plans

both with the https://github.com/cypreess/django-getpaid (which is a payment broker) they can solve all kind of problems with: plans, pricing, quotas (limits), invoicing, taxation, payments.

getpaid has a stable version, plans are still in development, but it is 100% usable at this point (I am using it personally).

Both have a pretty good documentation, that could be found on read the docs.

I hope that would help you.

Comment: As of 2020-04-19 django-getpaid has just released a new rewritten version with less magic during integration process.

Answer (score 4):

You might try looking around for quota systems. Your needs will probably be pretty tightly integrated with your application, so implementing a solution from the ground up is likely to be the right way to do it.

I see this which probably isn't quite what you need, but might give you some ideas: https://github.com/mpasternacki/django-quotas

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a decent answer for your question. But I dug a lot into this without finding a decent solution. I've stumbled upon [django-plans](https://github.com/cypreess/django-plans) but not even the examples work anymore. And their last commit was a year ago. But they do have issues that are months old.

I think since it's a very specific thing to countries' laws and eventually you will get to a point where the lib doesn't support what you wanna do. That said, I would develop my own. That's what I am doing now.